# Android - two textviews center sandwich

Tags: android, textview, center

I have two textviews in a tablelayout and I would like to center both textviews. Horizontally it works but vertically does not.

What's wrong with it?

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Feld1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Feld2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: can you post the full xml? What is the tablelayout width set to?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of those layout attributes when you're using a table layout.  Try removing all of them:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Field1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Field2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Try a layout_gravity attribute, I'll edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<!-- android:gravity="center_horizontal" will put the text at center of row horizontally -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Feld1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:background="@color/bluelight"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</TableRow>

<!-- Divider/ Separator -->
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/grey" />
</TableRow>

<!-- android:gravity="center_horizontal" will put the text at center of row horizontally -->

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/TableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Feld2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bluelight"            
        android:text="sample"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</TableRow>
```